# Display C# function progress on web page in real time?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax

I have a C# function on a web page that takes 10 seconds to run. While it's running, I need to tell users what's happening.

Is there a way I can update a div or label on web page saying 'I'm at module 1' etc.? I want to display progress as it is happening, not after it finishes.

Thanks!

Comment: Exactly 10 seconds or that's just a guesstimate? If it's always exactly 10 seconds, you could just use a javascript timer.

Comment: You can load a normal page that does not invoke the C# function, then call the page with C# function via ajax and update a div as 'waiting' or something until that function finishes , then when it does, update it as done. All that only if it really takes 10 seconds and does not timeout. If in case your function takes very very long that it times out you may want to poll using ajax to check the status and thus update the div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
 <asp:UpdateProgress ID="updProgress" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1" DisplayAfter="0">
       <ProgressTemplate>
           <div>
               <img src="../Resources/Images/YourImage.gif" />
               Loading...
           </div>
       </ProgressTemplate>
   </asp:UpdateProgress>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a jquery progressbar or something similiar to show the current status.
What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You should not run long running processes on the app pool.

Create a background service that monitors a message queue (or a database) - Same a message to the queue when you want the process to start. In the background service store status of the job in the database, and create a webservice to return the service. Use jquery to call the webservice and get the latest service.

This is the best way to achieve what you want.